# Additive and Multiplicative Combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays

Help! I am in dire need of help. I have a question given by a teacher and I need an answer! The question goes something along the lines of

Basically you have to enter a positive number that is greater than 1. After entering, the output would various numbers that add up to the number 6 (Example)

Example:
Input: 7

Output: The combinations (1, 6), (4, 3), (3, 4), (6, 1), (5,2) (2,5). output

I tired nothing worked

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [ask] and add your effort as [mcve] to the question. You said you tried but we see no code in the question that we could help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

**O(N^2)** method:

1. Create an empty array in javascript.
2. Loop from (1,n) where 'i' would be the iterator and nest another (i, n) loop where j would be the iterator.
3. If i+j = n then push (i,j) in the array.

```js
let n = 7;
const res = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    for(let j = i; j < n ; j++ ){
        if(i+j == n) {
            res.push({i,j}, {j, i});
        }
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: If you need O(N) time complexity an algorithm can be devised for that as well but considering your question I think O(N^2) would suffice as well.

Comment: What if i wanted to use the O(N^2) method towards multiplication. So for example: What if:
Input: 9
Output: (1,9),(3,3)(3,3)(9,1)?

Comment: Then just change i+j to i*j and add <= in the loop instead of <